# Most efficient way to implement a dynamic list on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to write a website with a list of certain elements. A specific user group should be able to add elements to this list. Another user group should be able to interact with the elements in some way.

To be more specific: This is about a list of courses, some users (students) should be able to declare their interest in a course. Administrators should be able to add courses to the list.

I'm struggling to come up with the most efficient way to implement this list. I guess I could use a table and implement a form that adds rows to it, but this seems like a horrible idea. Also, a connection to a database would probably be much better. However, I'm not sure how I'd combine my website with the database.

What's the best way to implement this kind of dynamic list on a website?

Best regards

Comment: you'd want the database access through some server side code, then probably use AJAX from the browser to make queries to update the dynamic content on the web page

Answer (score 1):

I would set up a [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) database, and allow users to register and create accounts through Firebase. I would then set database rules, allowing those who registered as admins to add courses and students to join courses.

After that, it would probably be fairly simple to implement a JS script that would render a list of courses from the database, and allow interactivity.